# how to handle %20 while string comparison in c#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to compare two strings but one of the string contains a white space at the end. I used Trim() and compared but didn't work because that white space is getting converted to %20 and I thing Trim does not remove that. it is something like `"abc"` and `"abc%20"` , what can I do in such situation to compare strings whih ignoring the case too?

Comment: Use Server.UrlDecode("abc%20") before comparison or write own comparer, that handle that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%20` is the url-encoded version of space.

You can't directly strip it off using `Trim()`, but you can use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) to decode the `%20` back to a space, then trim/do the comparison exactly as you would otherwise;

```cs
using System.Web;

//...

var test1 = "HELLO%20";
var test2 = "hello";

Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test1).Trim().
           Equals(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test2).Trim(),              
           StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

> true
```

Answer (score 6):

Use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode the strings:

```
string s1 = "abc ";
string s2 = "abc%20";
if (System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s1).Equals(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s2)))
{
    //equals...
}
```

In case of  WinForms or Console (or any non ASP.NET) project you will have to add reference to the `System.Web` assembly in your project.

Comment: `String.Equals` is not necessary, you can also use `==`.

Comment: @ggPeti I know, using `.Equals()` is just more readable to my eyes so when there's no risk of `null`s I'm using it.

Comment: Each to their own! I just figured OP would find this bit of info useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `"%20"` is the url encoded version of the `' '` (space) character. Are you comparing an encoded URL parameter? If so, you can use:

```
string str = "abc%20";
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str); // decoded becomes "abc "
```

If you need to trim any white spaces, you should do this for the decoded string. The `Trim` method does not understand or recognize the encoded whitespace characters.

```
decoded = decoded.Trim();
```

Now you can compare with the `decoded` variable using:

```
decoded.Equals(otherValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is probably the fastest way for case-insensitive comparison between strings.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if (System.Uri.UnescapeDataString("abc%20").ToLower() == myString.ToLower()) {}
```

Comment: [Note this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx).

Comment: You're right, I didn't thought of that. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
string before = "abc%20";
string after = before.Replace("%20", "").ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Replace` and since you mentioned case insensitivity `String.ToLower` like this:

```
var str1 = "abc";
var str2 = "Abc%20";
str1.Replace("%20", "").ToLower() == str2.Replace("%20", "").ToLower();
// will be true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the root problem is when you are with Encoding the Url. If you will use the character encoding, then you will never get %20. The default encoding used by HttpUtility.UrlEncode utf-8. here is the usage

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ãName Marcos", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))
```

And [Here, on Microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) You can read more about Character Encoding. 
And if you will do proper encoding you can avoid rest of the work

And here is what you asked -

The Second Case - If you have to compare two string as per your need, you need to Decode HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test)

```
bool result = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stringOne).Equals(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stringOne));
```

And result bool knows if they are equal or unequal

```
Console.WriteLine("Result is", result ? "equal." : "not equal.");
```

Hope it helps